# Remove whitespace from a file and output it to another file

Tags: python

I want to sort a file, and that part works. After sorting, I want to remove every whitespace line from the file and output it to another file.

I just can't figure it out, I really want help.

```py
bad_words = ["bad", "word"]


with open('naughtfile.txt') as oldfile, open('cleanfile', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
            newfile.write(line)
```

I want to sort the file, remove the whitespace lines and save it in another file.

Comment: What do you mean by whitespace line?

Comment: do you mean empty lines ? Empty line after removing whitespaces - `strip()` - has length 0 but you can also check it using `if not line.strip():`

Answer (score 0):

First you will want to read the contents of the file and split the lines into a list. Then you need to sort that list and write the list items that match the criteria to the other file. I'm not sure what you mean by whitespace line but I assumed those to just be blank lines.

```
bad_words = ["bad", "word"]

with open('naughtfile.txt') as oldfile, open('cleanfile.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    content = oldfile.read().splitlines()
    content.sort()
    for line in content:
        if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words) and not (line is "" or line.isspace()):
            newfile.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: that kinda worked , when i run the code this happens : https://prntscr.com/p10mhe

Comment: @DeagleusNebunus updated the code to handle for lines with spaces

Answer (score 0):

```
from string import whitespace
from itertools import chain


bad_words = ['bad', 'words']

with open(filepath_1, 'r') as old_file, open(filepath_2, 'w') as new_file:
    lines = old_file.readlines()
    lines.sort()

    for line in lines:
        # chain together the whitespace list and bad_words list.
        if not any(strng in line for strng in chain(whitespace, bad_words)):
            # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown your sorting, so I'm unsure what you want to do there.
As for the rest - I'd use a regex:

```
    import re
    # make regex that matches the bad words, plus empty lines
    bad_word = re.compile(r'bad|word|^\s*\n')
    # loop over the file and write the lines that don't match bad_word
    with open('naughtfile.txt') as oldfile, open('cleanfile.txt', 'w') as newfile:
        for line in oldfile:
            if bad_word.search(line):
                continue
            newfile.write(re.sub(r'\n', '', line))
```